# Unable to deploy custom files to Style library in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, visual-studio, module, style-library

I need to deploy the custom files like (CSS,js,images) into Style Library folder in SharePoint 2013 by using Visual Studio.

I created a module and edited the element.xml as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="Style Library" Url="Style Library">
    <File Path="Style Library\Sample.txt" Url="Style Library/Sample.txt" />
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

This is not working.

Comment: Can you please add more details, what is happening when you activate feature ? Does it activates successfully but files are not getting deployed or you are getting any error ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
          <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
            <Module Name="Style Library" Url="Style Library">
              <File Path="Style Library\Sample.txt" Url="Sample.txt" Type="GhostableInLibrary"/>
            </Module>
          </Elements>
```

I think the path of URL needs to be without the path of the module. I am missing also the type.